# Finding positive integer solutions to $3^x + 55=y^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I think it must be finite, $y$ is always even, but I don't know how to continue.

edit: with $x,y\in\mathbb Z$

Comment: Just by solving for $x$ or $y$ you can see that the solution set isn't finite.  It's uncountably infinite.

Comment: I guess he means in integers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure $x$ has to be even too, but I don't have anything further than that.

Comment: $x$ has to be even from considering mod 4.

Comment: By inspection, there is the "obvious" solution of $x=2$ and $y=-8$ or $y=8$.

Comment: $\pmod{4}$ gives $x$ even. Now write $$55=(y+3^{\frac{x}{2}})(y-3^{\frac{x}{2}})$$

Comment: $x=6$, $y=28$ is the next solution.

Comment: ok if y is even then its last digit can be 0,4 or 6. and if x is odd then the last digit is either 3 or 7 which is not possible, but how is the even case

Comment: (fix) As quick observations, you have $y\equiv 0\bmod2$, $y^2\equiv1\bmod3$ (equivalently $y\not\equiv 0 \bmod 3$), $y\equiv\pm 1\bmod5$. $3^x+55\equiv(−1)^2x+3\equiv0\bmod4$, which forces x even as Dennis says.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint** Modulo $4$ we have

$$(-1)^x \equiv 1 \pmod{4} \Rightarrow x =2k$$

Then

$$(y-3^k)(y+3^k) =55$$

Now all you have to do is check all possible factorizations of $55: 1 \times 55$ or $5 \times 11$.

Comment: ah, ok (2,8) is the other solution then.